# Enable Wifi Programatically or via Activity?

Tags: android, wifi

Is it considered best practice or more acceptable or, for any other reason, preferable, to initialise WiFI on an Android device via a programmatic approach:

```
WifiManager oWiFIMgr = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
oWiFIMgr .setWifiEnabled(true);
```

vs. launching the WiFI settings activity?

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the purpose of your app.
If you are going to create a home screen widget like wifi toggle or something similar, the user would be pleased if just touching the widget turns On the wifi, but if its some app that just require the wifi access to  do certain task, it would be better to open the wifi page allowing the user to take his own choice.

What really matters is you should design your app in such a way that once the purpose of wifi is done, it should be turned off again.

PS: No matter which choice you make in your app design the permissions of that app is going to be displayed during the installation.

So just keep in mind for the user friendliness of your app and its performance.

Answer (score 0):

In **Android Q (Android 10)** you can't enable/disable wifi programmatically anymore. So you don't have a choice, you need to use **Settings Panel** to toggle wifi connectivity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Always let user take those kind of decisions, enable WiFi, GPS .. stuff like that .. new Google maps app does that .. i think it's best ..